# Nestjs circular dependency

Tags: nestjs

I have module A and B that depend on each other. Module C depends on Module B.
I used `forwardRef()` for modules A and B, but I didn't for C and B,

```js
// a.module.ts
@Module(
    {
        imports  : [
            forwardRef(() => ModuleB),
            forwardRef(() => ModuleC),
        ],
        providers: [
            ServiceA,
        ],
        exports  : [
            ServiceA,
        ]
    },
)
export class ModuleA {}

// a.service.ts
    constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceB)) private readonly serviceB: ServiceB,
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceC)) private readonly serviceC: ServiceC,
    ) {}

// b.module.ts
@Module(
    {
        imports  : [
            forwardRef(() => ModuleA ),
            ModuleC,
        ],
        providers: [
            ServiceB,
        ],
        exports  : [
            ServiceB,
        ]
    },
)
export class ModuleB {}

// b.service.ts
    constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceA)) private readonly serviceA: ServiceA,
                                            private readonly serviceC: ServiceC,
    ) {}

// c.module.ts
@Module(
    {
        imports  : [
            forwardRef(() => ModuleA),
        ],
        providers: [
            ServiceB,
        ],
        exports  : [
            ServiceB,
        ]
    },
)
export class ModuleC {}

// c.service.ts
    constructor(
        @Inject(forwardRef(() => ServiceA)) private readonly serviceA: ServiceA,
    ) {}
```

It causes a circular dependency between the modules issue, but I can't track the root as module A is in another module, and the modules are deeply integrated/nested.
I don't know how circular dependencies are resolved in NestJS, or how to debug better.
I read that [I should avoid it as much as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65671381/1934402).

Comment: Can you show the error you're receiving? And possibly replace the `ModuleA/B/C` with the actual names? Right now it looks like `ModuleB` imports` ModuleC` and `ModuleB` and `ModuleC` both provide a `ServiceB` which may be confusing things

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work but you should review your architecture because so many circular dependencies are most certainly a bad pratice.

```js
// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [AModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}


// a.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [BModule, CModule],
  providers: [AService],
  exports: [AService],
})
export class AModule {}

// a.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class AService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => BService)) private bService: BService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CService)) private cService: CService,
  ) {}
}

// b.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => AModule), CModule],
  providers: [BService],
  exports: [BService],
})
export class BModule {}

// b.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class BService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AService)) private aService: AService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CService)) private cService: CService,
  ) {}
}

// c.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => BModule), forwardRef(() => AModule)],
  providers: [CService],
  exports: [CService],
})
export class CModule {}

// c.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class CService {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AService)) private aService: AService) {}
}
```

> Module C depends on Module B

You wrote this but in your code, Module C actually depends on module A, so I followed the latter.
Also, in your module C, you have `ServiceB` in your `providers`. I guess it's just a copy/paste mistake but it adds to the confusion.

#### My thought process (I'm not sure I got it right but it works)

`AModule` is the first imported (in `app.module.ts`), so it's the first that should be initialized. That's why the `imports` array does not contain any forward references.

Same with `BModule`, which should be instanciated in second and finally, `CModule` (that's why it contains 2 forward references, because it has lowest priority).

After that, I inserted `@Inject(forwardRef(() => BService))`, until every error like `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AService (BService, ?).` was gone.